# output difference of two values same column to another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anhone help me out or point me in the right direction? What is simplest way to get from current table to output table??

Current Table

ID         |          type     |          amount             |

2          |          A          |          19                    |

2          |          B          |          6                      |

3          |          A          |          5                      |

3          |          B          |          11                    |

4          |          A          |          1                      |

4          |          B          |          23                    |

Desires output

ID         |          type     |          amount             |          change           |

2          |          A          |          19                    |          13                  |

2          |          B          |          6                      |          -6                  |

3          |          A          |          5                      |          -22                |

3          |          B          |          11                    |                                |

4          |          A          |          1                      |                                |

4          |          B          |          23                    |                                |

Comment: Please explain the logic for the "change" column?  And why is it missing on three rows?  Where does -22 come from?

Comment: hi gordan thanks for responding i want to subtract 2a: 19 and 2b: 6 to give 13. -22 comes from last row amount subtract from second last row amount 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how the values are put on rows.  You can, for instance, subtract the "B" value from the "A" value for any given id.  For instance:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 'A'
             then amount - max(amount) filter (type = 'B') over (partition by id)
        end) as diff_a_b
from t;
```